# Drupal Commerce: Print order?

Tags: commerce

Is there any module that would give option to print order in commerce?

Im trying to create option to print orders for packaging department but can't find a way that would allow customer details and order line items.

Comment: Hi Tuomas, you should mark the response from generalconsensus as your accepted answer. :)

Comment: I have the same issue,how can I print the order?I don't want to send it as an email...

Comment: The accepted answer, even if is right (won't deserve downvote) don't solve the question. There must be an answer to 'how to print', not 'how to email' the order

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Through [Rules module](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) you can achieve this:

1. First step create a custom rule at /admin/config/workflow/rules/reaction/add
2. Select the React on event: "Completing the checkout process"
3. Add a new Action: "Send mail"
4. Once you add the email addresses from/to, than add the replacement fields in the body text of the email. I suggest: [commerce-order:order-number], [commerce-order:type], [commerce-order:commerce-line-items]. But you can figure that part out.

Save your Rule.

Get a Beer and celebrate you are now forwarding new orders to your customer fulfillment department.