# Drupal Commerce: Print order for warehouse

Tags: commerce

I followed [Drupal Commerce: Print order?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/45340/drupal-commerce-print-order) solution:

> Through Rules you can achieve this by creating a Rule within the Rules
>   module:
>
> First step create a custom rule at
>   /admin/config/workflow/rules/reaction/add Select the React on event:
>   "Completing the checkout process" Add a new Action: "Send mail" Once
>   you add the email addresses from/to, than add the replacement fields
>   in the body text of the email. I suggest:
>   [commerce-order:order-number], [commerce-order:type],
>   [commerce-order:commerce-line-items]. But you can figure that part
>   out. Save your Rule.

I receive the email but I do not have a proper list of ordered products, instead I have numbers. One per article but the change on each order even if the articles are the same.

How can I have a proper order listing in the email?

Answer (score 2):

You will want to use the Commerce Message module: https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_message

This module provides a `!order-summary` token which embeds an order's line item summary. This token only works, however, if the Message bundle has the `message_commerce_order` field.

You can either programmatically add this to a new Message bundle. Or, the easy route, clone the default admin notification and adjust as needed!